# Installed server but track the desktop kernel

Tags: 10.04, kernel, updates

Is it possible to have a system originally installed with the Ubuntu 10.04 server edition both use and track updates of the desktop kernel (i.e. linux-image-generic instead of linux-image-server)?

I assumed the difference between the packages tracked by the desktop and server editions would be reflected in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but the two look similar to me. So, how does a system know which kernel to track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. To install use:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-restricted-modules
```

Then it will know to update both. Although your better off using the Server kernel if your just running a vanilla server install. It's better optimized.